# How do I thank the moderators for being so responsive to raised flags?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging, moderators

The title says it all.  I've raised several flags over time that required moderator intervention and the moderators have been very responsive.  Is there a preferred way to say Thank You?

Comment: I don't think there is any way, since it is expected of them as part of moderation duty. We appreciate the gesture non the less, from my part at least thank you. A good way to show gratitude could be help with site maintenance. Dealing with [Review Queues](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review) is one of the sites most demanding aspects, helping keep them in check would be very appreciated

Comment: I was raised to believe, and 60ish years later still believe, that thanking people for doing their job well, even if that's expected, is a good thing.  So thank you, for doing well that which is expected of you.  (I do indeed work on the review queues every day.  I also believe that pitching in improves everyone's experience.)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, keep up the great attitude

Comment: Here for example: Thank you all for your commitment and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments by [Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos):

- paraphrased: StackExchange appears to provide no formal mechanism because it is expected as part of moderation duty.
- A good way to show gratitude could be help with site maintenance. Dealing with Review Queues is one of the sites most demanding aspects; helping keep them in check would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Complete noob. Please find a way so that we (from foreign cultures at least) can express emotion. Cheers

Comment: Here is what I do on answers to my questions: 1) I leave a comment thanking the individual in the comment section of the answer.  2) If it is a good answer but doesn't fully solve my problem, I _upvote_ the answer, as a way of showing gratitude.  3) If it is the best answer to the question, I _accept_ the answer. That also shows gratitude.   you might want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .  Saying thank you is kind, and that's how this StackExchange culture seems to do it.